# In AngularJS, how do I generate a piece of content from template and insert it in the DOM when a link is clicked

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-compile

I have a number of links on the page, dynamically generated like so:

```
<a href="#" class="more-info-item" ng-click="showStats(item, $event)">
   More information
</a>
```

I also have a simple custom template that should show an item's name:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="iteminfo.html">
  <div class="item-name">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</script>
```

What I would like to do is: when the link is clicked, to dynamically compile the template, and insert it in the DOM right after the link. I tried using $compile within showStats method to compile the template, but I got an error that $compile wasn't found. How would I go about doing this (and also provide item as part of the scope for the newly generated template)?

Comment: Did you inject `$compile` into whatever controller/service/directive `showStats` is defined in?

Comment: Is it always the same template or is it associated with the specific item?

Comment: @MarcKline I did not -- perhaps that's my problem. I'll try that and see how far I can get.

Comment: @tasseKATT It's always the same template, though it's quite a bit more complex than that; I just simplified it for this example.

Comment: @MarcKline -- thanks, that was the issue. I think I got it working the way I wanted to now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a custom directive which injects the item dynamically using ng-if:

[View Solution with Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/itt4yIdLeg74BL3YlLwr?p=preview)

**html:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="iteminfo.html">
    <div class="item-name" ng-if="item.visible">
            {{item.name}}
    </div>
</script>
<div ng-repeat="item in items" >
    <a href="#" class="more-info-item" more-info="item" ng-click="item.visible =!item.visible">
          More information
    </a>
</div>
```

**script:**

```
        angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('ctrl', function($scope)  {
                $scope.items = [{name:'apples', visible:false},{name:'pears', visible:false},{name:'oranges', visible:false}];
        })
        .directive('moreInfo', function($compile,$templateCache) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: '=',
                    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                            var itemInfo = angular.element($templateCache.get('iteminfo.html'));
                            var lfn = $compile(itemInfo);
                            element.parent().append(itemInfo);
                            lfn(scope);
                    }
            };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, @pixelbits. This is much more along the lines of what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in **[ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)** directive in `AngularJS`

Try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UGj7t/1/)**

**html**

```
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <a href="#" class="more-info-item" ng-click="showStats(item, $event)">
        More information
   </a>
  <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>

<!-- iteminfo.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="iteminfo.html">
  <div class="item-name">
   {{item.name}}
  </div>
</script>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.flag = false;
    $scope.item = {
        name: 'Manu'
    };
    $scope.showStats = function (item, event) {
        $scope.item = item;
        $scope.template = "iteminfo.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty clever solution, but I was hoping to inject the item dynamically, rather than have it already in the DOM. I simplified it for the purposes of this example, but this item info template is actually quite complex, and I would prefer to only have one of them in the DOM at the time (the plan is to wipe out the other existing ones before adding a new one). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: hey do you want to inject the `iteminfo.html` content from controller